# What's the diffence between struct and new struct?

Tags: c++

In C++, I have seen 2 ways to create a new struct:

1.

```
StructA a;
a.member1 = ...;
foo(&a); // void foo(StructA* a);
```

2.

```
StructA* a = new StructA;
a->member1 = ...;
foo(a);
```

What are the difference and implications of these 2 code snipets?

Thanks

Comment: The second one is a pointer to a struct; the first is a direct variable declaration.

Comment: What do you think is the difference? I'm asking to understand how/what to answer, since your answer will give me a "level".

Comment: The second one requires you to now manage what you just allocated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What and where are the stack and heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: Thanks Chris & harmic. No thanks to those downvoters who didn't care to give a reason!

Comment: The downvotes are because you should know the answer to this after finishing a C++ tutorial.

Comment: In addition to the other comments above and below, the first declaration allocates the space for the structure from the stack (typically), and the second declaration allocates space for the structure from the heap. The pointer in the second declaration could be stored on the stack or in a register, depending on how the compiler optimizes the code.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in a nutshell:
`StructA a` declares a variable that is a StructA.
`StructA* a` declares a pointer that points to a StructA.

The implications:

The variable `StructA` is can be immediately used to store data.
The pointer `StructA*` must be set to point to an actual struct before it can be used to store data.

The variable `StructA` will automatically be deallocated when the current block exits.
While the pointer `StructA*` will be deallocated when the current block exits, the data it is pointing to (created with `new`) will not go away until `delete` is called.  If `delete` is never called, then your program will have a memory leak.